# skipping after_filter in inherited controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my applications controller I have an `after_filter` that sets the value of `last_page` in the session to be the current requests URL. When I create a new session in the sessions controller, that page url is `/signin`, but since it has to go through `SessionsController#create`, the `last_page` changes to `/signin` so I lose what the actual page was before the user clicked sign-in.

I essentially what to have this:

```
after_filter :set_last_page, except: [sessions#new]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `skip_before_filter` and [`skip_after_filter`](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_after_filter) helpers for disabling before/after filters in your derived controllers.

You want to add `skip_after_filter :set_last_page, only: "new"` to your Sessions controller.

Comment: boom, awesome! Thanks for the link as well